# How to restricts public uploads files in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, restrict

How to restrict the direct access to files in Laravel (`http://localhost/laravel-blog/public/uploads/sample.jpg`)

The problem is: If it shows the folder it will try to access other files, directly opening the document path.

If I put in URL uploads then it will return nothing, but If I put full URL with the path then it is accessible. So, how can I stop it?

Is it possible to access images outside the public folder?

Comment: you would have directory listings off for the site and things in `public` are there to be accessible

Comment: Yes, i have a public directory, but I need to restrict them

Comment: the point of things being in `public` is that they are publicly accessible

Comment: If  it possible to access images outside public folder?